# Validation of $\frac{\partial \mathcal{R} (\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}^T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I wanted to validate whether my differentiation is correct here

Let $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{x}) = \sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}}$.
Note that $\mathbf{x}$ is $(n \times 1)$ vector and $\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{\Sigma}^T$, then:

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{R} (\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}^T} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{x} \right)^{-1/2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}^T} \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}^ = \frac{  \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{x}} }$$

This boils down to knowing what is:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}^T} \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}$$

noone knows? :)

**EDIT**:

it was actually:

$\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{x}) = \sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}}$

And I cannot use the tool from comments, because when I set $y=x^T$, then the tool is saying that it cannot multiply column vector by a matrix, since it deems $y$ to be column vector by default...

I know for sure that that answer above is incorrect :)

$\Sigma$ is a symmetric matrix.

**EDIT EDIT**:

Since I know that the answer to $\frac{\partial \mathcal{R} (\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ is $\frac{  \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{x}} }$, and since differentiating wrt to transpose converts you from column vector answer to row vector answer, then this must generalize to my case too, hence, I believe the answer is:

$$\frac{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}}}$$

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**:

Nope, cannot be correct, because then my dimensions aren't right. The answer must be $n \times 1$, like in the original solution.

Comment: I utilized a tool herein http://www.matrixcalculus.org/.
It seems that your vector $\mathbf{x}$ is a row vector. Otherwise the solution matches.

Comment: it is actually a column vector, but if you do a change of variable like $y=x^T$, then it basically shows that the result is in fact: $\frac{\mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}}{ \sqrt{ \mathbf{x} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}^T}}$

Comment: oops... that cannot be true. it's: $\frac{\mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}^T}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}^T}}$

Comment: In my humble view, your equation should read $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{x}) = \sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}}$, otherwise things just don't fit in a first principle of linear algebra.

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: Your second edit is the correct answer.

Comment: @greg $x^T \Sigma$ ?

Comment: For a scalar-valued function $R$, if you know that the gradient is the (column) vector $\,\Big(g=\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}\Big)\,$ then its transpose must be the row vector $\,\Big(g^T=\frac{\partial R}{\partial x^T}\Big)\,$

Comment: @greg thanks! .